# I can't sign in with another account in visual studio community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I had visual studio community 2015 and I want to delete the older account and use my new one.

I log out my older account and I try my new one, visual studio close automatically.

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, Please check the following steps:

1. Check the connection of your network. And then open the Internet Explorer, open one website, if it could be opened successfully, indicating your network is well.
2. Maybe your IE doesn’t trust the Visual Studio web page or the sign in page, try to add the https://www.visualstudio.com/ , https://login.microsoftonline.com/  and https://login.live.com/ to your trusted zone.
3. If the above doesn’t help, try to enable the JavaScript in Internet Explorer because if the JavaScript is disabled, you will not able to sign in.

   Go to `Tools -> Internet Options -> Security Tab`, and then click the Internet zone, depending on whether you have to customize your Internet security settings, select one of the following options:

   - If you do not have to customize your Internet security settings, click Default Level.
   - If you have to customize your Internet security settings, click Custom level, scroll down to the Active scripting section, and then click Enable.
4. If none of the above helps, please try to create a new account to see whether you could sign in.